# Searching data with combobox codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I'm Giovanni,
I got a problem on my code, seems my code work but why the result is unmatch with the values on my combobox..

Can you tell me what's wrong?

Here's my code (on controller. function pencarian_indeks)

```
function pencarian_indeks() {

    //muat library form validation
    $this->load->library('form_validation');

    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
        {
        //set aturan validasi untuk setiap field isian
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('tanggal', 'Tanggal', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('kategori', 'Kategori', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('tahun', 'Tahun', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('bulan', 'Bulan', 'required');


    //cek apakah form validasi berhasil
    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)//jika validasi gagal
    {

    $this->session->set_flashdata('pesan', validation_errors());
    redirect(base_url() . 'indeks');
    }
    else //jika validasi berhasil
    {
    $data['kategori'] = $this->input->post('kategori');
    $data['tanggal'] = $this->input->post('tanggal');
    $data['bulan'] = $this->input->post('bulan');
    $data['tahun'] = $this->input->post('tahun');

        $this->db->where('DAY(created_at)',$data['tanggal']);
        $this->db->where('MONTH(created_at)',$data['bulan']);
        $this->db->where('YEAR(created_at)',$data['tahun']);

        $this->db->where('kategori', $data['kategori']);
        $this->db->from('news');

        //Pagination init
        $pagination['base_url']     = base_url().'/pencarian/index/page/';
        $pagination['total_rows']   = $this->db->count_all_results();
        $pagination['full_tag_open'] = "<p><div class=\"pagination\">";
        $pagination['full_tag_close'] = "</div></p>";
        $pagination['cur_tag_open'] = "<span class=\"current\">";
        $pagination['cur_tag_close'] = "</span>";
        $pagination['num_tag_open'] = "<span class=\"disabled\">";
        $pagination['num_tag_close'] = "</span>";
        $pagination['per_page']     = "3";
        $pagination['uri_segment'] = 4;
        $pagination['num_links']    = 4;

        $this->pagination->initialize($pagination);

        $data['query'] = $this->news_model->indeks_berita($pagination['per_page'],$this->uri->segment(4,0),$data['tahun'],$data['bulan'],$data['tanggal'],$data['kategori']);

        print_r($data['query']);//coba dicek dlu datanya.. 
        exit;

        $this->load->vars($data);
        $data['hasil5'] = $this->news_model->tampil_populer(2);
        $data = array_merge($data,admin_info());
        $this->parser->parse('frontend/indeks/indeks',$data);

    }
        } else {
           echo "Hasil Pencarian Tidak Ditemukan!!";
        }



}
```

and on my model (function indeks_berita)

```
    function indeks_berita($perPage, $uri,$tanggal,$bulan,$tahun,$kategori) {
    $this->db->select('*');

    if($tahun)
        $this->db->where('YEAR(created_at)',$tahun);
    if($bulan)
        $this->db->where('MONTH(created_at)',$bulan);
    if($tanggal)
        $this->db->where('DAY(created_at)',$tanggal);
    if($kategori)
        $this->db->where('kategori', $kategori);
    $this->db->order_by('id', 'asc');

    $getData = $this->db->get('news', $perPage, $uri);

    print_r ($this->db->last_query());
    //print_r ($getData->result_array());
    exit();

    if ($getData->num_rows() > 0){
        return $getData->result_array();
    }else{
        return null;
    }
}
```

on my view (the comboboxes)

```
<p>Lihat Arsip Tanggal :
    <select name="kategori">
            <option value="" selected>Pilih kategori</option>
            <option value="news">News</option>
            <option value="bandung_city">Bandung City</option>
            <option value="hot_gossip">Hot Gossip</option>
            <option value="sainstek">Sains & Tek</option>
            <option value="kriminal">Kriminalitas</option>
            <option value="persibnews">#PERSIBONTHENEWS</option>
</select>
    <select name="tahun">
            <option value="" selected>Pilih Tahun</option>
            <option value="2013">2013</option>
            <option value="2014">2014</option>
            <option value="2015">2015</option>
            <option value="2016">2016</option>
            <option value="2017">2017</option>
            <option value="2018">2018</option>
</select>
<select name="bulan">
            <option value="" selected>Pilih Bulan</option>
            <option value="1">Januari</option>
            <option value="2">Februari</option>
            <option value="3">Maret</option>
            <option value="4">April</option>
            <option value="5">Mei</option>
            <option value="6">Juni</option>
            <option value="7">Juli</option>
            <option value="8">Agustus</option>
            <option value="9">September</option>
            <option value="10">Oktober</option>
            <option value="11">November</option>
            <option value="12">Desember</option>
</select>

<select name="tanggal">
            <option value="" selected>Pilih</option>
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
            <option value="5">5</option>
            <option value="6">6</option>
            <option value="7">7</option>
            <option value="8">8</option>
            <option value="9">9</option>
            <option value="10">10</option>
            <option value="11">11</option>
            <option value="12">12</option>
            <option value="13">13</option>
            <option value="14">14</option>
            <option value="15">15</option>
            <option value="16">16</option>
            <option value="17">17</option>
            <option value="18">18</option>
            <option value="19">19</option>
            <option value="20">20</option>
            <option value="21">21</option>
            <option value="22">22</option>
            <option value="23">23</option>
            <option value="24">24</option>
            <option value="25">25</option>
            <option value="26">26</option>
            <option value="27">27</option>
            <option value="28">28</option>
            <option value="29">29</option>
            <option value="30">30</option>
            <option value="31">31</option>
</select>

<input type="submit" value="Cari!" name="cari" id="cari"/>
```

And here's the output query when I submitted that code :

```
SELECT * FROM (`news`) WHERE YEAR(created_at) = '2' AND MONTH(created_at) = '17' AND DAY(created_at) = 'bandung_city' AND `kategori` = '2014' ORDER BY `id` asc LIMIT 3
```

(seems not right)

Thank you, I'm glad if you help me to find what's wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your form `action` seems to be incorrect you do not have any `indeks` method inside `indeks` contorller.

Change is as below

`<form action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>indeks/pencarian_indeks" method="post">`

Answer (score 0):

It seems like that passing the order of the arguments to your model function is wrong.

Instead of this

```
$data['query'] = $this->news_model->indeks_berita(
          $pagination['per_page'],
          $this->uri->segment(4,0),
          $data['tahun'], // it seems that model function accepts tangall as 3rd arg
          $data['bulan'], 
          $data['tanggal'],// it seems that model function accepts tahun as 5th arg
          $data['kategori']
);
```

Try

```
$data['query'] = $this->news_model->indeks_berita(
          $pagination['per_page'],
          $this->uri->segment(4,0),
          $data['tanggal'],
          $data['bulan'],
          $data['tahun'],         
          $data['kategori']
);
```

Comment: Still not work sir.. the output query seems like this :
SELECT * FROM (`news`) WHERE YEAR(created_at) = '2' AND MONTH(created_at) = '17' AND DAY(created_at) = 'bandung_city' AND `kategori` = '2014' ORDER BY `id` asc LIMIT 3

Comment: try printing out your post vars

Comment: how?? and where should I put that?

Comment: print_r($_POST); in ur controller